# Mathjax in C++ console

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, mathjax, derivative

I am making an console application in C++ to find derivative of a mathematical function for my school project, but the results are hard to understand for example like

## ((sin(x)/cos(log(x^3 - 2*x))*3*x-2sqrt(x))

so, is there any way to get a better output. I would really like something like:

[image: \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{(\log{(x^3 - 2x)})*3x}}-2\sqrt{x}]

I know mathjax is not for c++ console but can i do something like to print it Mathjax format and use other applications maybe like chrome to display it properly? and can I do it offline?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 - You've completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: Removed. Thanks.

Comment: the console is not related to C++ and google chrome

Comment: we can atleast start start other applicants like chrome from the console, but cant me input some intents (like in android) to load a given file

Answer (score 1):

Make an HTML page that displays an equation using MathJAX. Copy most of that page (except for the part with the actual equation) into your C++ program and put it in a `static const char []` like this:

```
static const char htmlhead[] =
     "<html><body>\n"
     "<p>Some random text.</p>";

static const char htmltail[] =
     "</body></html>";
```

Then you can output the head, write some custom C++ to print out the equation in MathJAX then print out the tail. Use an `::std::ofstream` to send all that to a file ending in `.html`. Then you can load that file up on Chrome with a `file:///` URL.

Comment: can't I directly start chrome with the file loaded. Like something system("start chrome.exe); but in this case, we here only start chrome not loaded the file.

Comment: @Snowfox that's going to be highly system specific. It is possible, yes. But not possible to do in a portable way.

Comment: @Snowfox - So, maybe you could tag the question with which system you cared about? I'm only going to be able to answer if it's Linux and maybe if it's OS X. I despise Windows, and everything it stands for, and avoid writing code for it if I possibly can, so I really would have no idea there, and wouldn't want to talk about it even if I did.