# Rendering mathematical equations with AST in SFML C++

Tags: c++, optimization, textures, sfml, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to render a mathematical equation from an AST tree in SFML.

My current approach is to have a function that create base `sf::Texture` from characters, such as:

```
sf::Texture ASTHelper::GetTextureFromDefaultChar(char c) {
    sf::Text tmp;
    tmp.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    tmp.setString(std::string(1, c));
    tmp.setFont(this->textFont);
    tmp.setCharacterSize(this->fontSize);

    int x = tmp.getLocalBounds().width;
    int y = tmp.getLocalBounds().height;

    sf::RenderTexture tex;
    tex.create(x, y);
    tex.clear();
    tex.draw(tmp);
    tex.display();

    sf::Texture returnTex = tex.getTexture();
    
    return returnTex;
}
```

then merge/move/copy those textures into more convoluted equations while traversing the AST tree.

[image]

For example, given an expression like `(x+1)`, I can use `GetTextureFromDefaultChar()` for each character, then merge the textures together horizontally.

Problem is, seems like merging and copying `sf::Texture`/`sf::RenderTexture` is **strongly** discouraged. And certainly not **every frame**.

- https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=17566.0
- https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=18020.0
- https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10512.0

I've also look into other API/libraries to see if anything could be use in C++ (since I don't want to reinvent the wheel), and MathJax seems to be used a lot ([Mathjax in C++ console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356452/mathjax-in-c-console)), but in browsers.

So,

1. Is there a better way than merging/copying `sf::Texture` and `sf::RenderTexture` (or some completely different arrangements that I may have overlook)?

and

2. If not, are there any different C++ libraries that support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have every math symbol as `sf::Int/FloatRect` which would be their position in `sf::Texture` that would contain every single one of them.

Then you could just calculate their position in one line i.e. how would they be positioned if you would like to draw them.

Then draw these as `sf::Sprite` or `sf:RectangleShape` to one `sf::RenderTexture`, display it and now you have a texture which is made out of your symbols.

This way you don't draw all textures nor create that `sf::RenderTexture` every frame from scratch. Also, making another math equation into a texture would just require to call `sf::RenderTexture::clear(sf::Color::Transparent)` and repeating the same steps as before.

This way there is no merging, copying of textures, just one texture sheet of symbols which are drawn into one renderTexture.

Comment: The calculation is the hard part, I mean. A lot of math equations don't just go horizontally, they shift up, down, go left, right and got scaled around. That's why I want to abuse the textures at first. But a good idea nonetheless, I will try it out.

Comment: Remember that that `sf::FloatRect` gives you size of that symbol, so it makes a little bit easier to calculate it.